# Laravel start function not calling from inside a namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel, laravel-4

So I'm writing a Laravel 4 app and I've setup namespaces. I'm just trying to write some systemwide functionality that I can execute from anywhere mainly to create menus/setup language/currencies etc.

I have directory to global called "library" which has currently a file called Menu.php inside it which looks as follows:

```
    <?php

namespace Library;

use AppName\Model\Menu as MenuModel;

class Menu {

    public static function BuildMenu($id = 1) {

        //retrieve menu
        $menu = MenuModel::GetMenu($id);

        //sort content for page
        $data = $menu->toArray();
        print_r($data);
    }

}
```

I am currently attempting to call the BuildMenu function in the filters.php file with the following:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    //
    View::share('Menu', Library\Menu::BuildMenu());
});
```

I get a class 'Library\Menu' not found error from laravel. I'm presuming this is something to do with my lack of knowledge of namespaces so any clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: why are you using a framework in language that you do not understand ?

Comment: ...I understand PHP I just haven't used namespaces before as I have been working on legacy apps. Please dont comment if you arent going to be helpful

Comment: [This could be helpful too.](http://heera.it/laravel-4-view-composer-master-layout)

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your library path to composer.json ?

if not, just add it to autoload > classmap >> app/library

and run artisan dump-autoload

should be fine.

Comment: I added it to global.php as: app_path().'/library' instead. This should perform the same I believe?

Comment: as it mention in the source "In addition to using Composer, you may use the Laravel class loader to load your controllers and models ..."